# NDepend VSTS Build task run but do not produce any result

Tags: ndepend, azure-pipelines-build-task

I have configured the NDepend VSTS Task as [indicated](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/vsts-integration-ndepend#HowToConfigureHub) but the dashboard stay empty and redirect me to the configuration doc.

I also checked the "Stop the Build when at least one Quality Gate fails" option and even if NDepend detect 2 gates failed, the build is still considered as successful.

Here is the NDepend task logs:

> ##[section]Starting: NDependTask
>   -------------------------------------------------------------
>   Task         : NDepend Task
>   Description  : NDepend Task
>   Version      : 1.7.0
>   Author       : NDEPEND
>   Help         : Replace with markdown to show in help
>   -------------------------------------------------------------
>   Preparing task execution handler.
>   Executing the powershell script: d:\a_tasks\NDependTask_94137ea2-81f0-411a-9527-b1400d722332\1.7.0\ndepend.ps1
>
> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException
>   Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Url'. The argument is null or empty.
>   Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.
>   No previous build analyzed by ndepend is found to compare with.
>
> ##[warning]The ndproj file is not defined, the default one will be used
>
> D:\a_tasks\NDependTask_94137ea2-81f0-411a-9527-b1400d722332\1.7.0\Integration\VSTS\VSTSAnalyzer.exe /outputDirectory "d:\a\1\a" /sourceDirectory "d:\a\1\s" /excludePattern ".*test.*" /identifier "default" /hub "https://laedit2.visualstudio.com/IASI/_apps/hub/ndepend.ndependextension.NDepend.Hub" /coverageDir "d:\a\1\TestResults;d:\a\1\s;d:\a\1\s" /stopBuild  /errorCode 1
>   Run Analysis!
>   2 quality gates fail.
>    - 'Critical Rules Violated' value 2 rules greater than fail threshold 0 rules
>    - 'Debt Rating per Namespace' value 1 namespaces greater than fail threshold 0 namespaces
>   ##[error]Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool VSTSAnalyzer.exe
>
> ##[section]Finishing: NDependTask

Do I need to configure something else?

The Visual Studio integration of NDepend works perfectly with the same ndproj on my computer.

**EDIT:**
I use the trial version of the task.
The problem is reproducible with the following steps:

1. new console application (.net 4.5.2)
2. NDepend menu in Visual Studio / Attach new NDepend project to solution
3. publish the project to VSTS and create this build definition based on the Visual Studio proposed:
   [image: VSTS Build Definition]

And the NDepend Build Task:
[image]

VSTS Build result despite the `Unexpected exit code 1 returned from tool VSTSAnalyzer.exe`:
[image]

[Here](https://1.sharebylink.com/1/?XbpECfRyJ9v0) are the project with ndproj and the build logs.

I have noticed the following exception:

> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingValidationException
>   Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Url'. The argument is null or empty.
>   Provide an argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

But I cannot find the 'Url' parameter anywhere in the NDepend task definition, so I don't know if it is related.

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue. (.net unit test with code coverage) There isn't any error in NDependTask. What's the project that you build and test? Can you share a simple project on the OneDrive? On the other hand, do you send the email to vsts@ndepend.com?

Comment: I have reproduced it with a new project and updated the question with all information. I will send a mail to vsts@ndepend.com.

Comment: Could you share a simple project and detail build log on the OneDrive?

Comment: Here are the project and logs zip: https://1.sharebylink.com/1/?XbpECfRyJ9v0

Comment: I still can't reproduce this issue with your project. Send the email to vsts@ndepend.com and post the solution here if others have the similar issue.

Comment: Already sent, I will post the answer if they are able to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following email exchange with the VSTS team from NDepend, It appears that there was issues in the NDepend VSTS Build Task but they have been fixed.

That said, it is worth to notice that if the "Stop the Build when at least one Quality Gate fails" option is checked and your project have some quality gates failed, the NDepend result won't be stored.
So if your project never had a successful build, the NDepend dashboard will redirect you to the "How-To" section.